# How to use webRTC with face-API to detect facial expression on real time video?

Tags: javascript, node.js, video, webrtc, face-api

I want to combine two API (webRTC and face API) where the system can detect people's expressions in real-time those people are attending a video conference meeting,

I tried passing the meeting video as parameter on face API but it doesn't work.

Please Help Me How can I get data and save it on the firebase database?

If you need a Full Project Code You can download it from here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qeu_GU2PkFcAcJ2OMQVvCDdvZvmgRx5i/view

WebRTC code: 
Where I Can create a Meeting Room. For this I just Use [Peers JS](https://peerjs.com/) API

```
const socket = io('/');

const videoGrid = document.getElementById('video-grid');


const peer = new Peer(undefined, {
path: '/peerjs',
host: '/',
port: '443'
}); 

const myVideo = document.createElement('video');

myVideo.muted = true;
const peers = {}
let myVideoStream;

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
video: true,
audio: true
}).then(stream => {
myVideoStream = stream;
addVideoStream(myVideo, stream);

peer.on('call', call => {
    call.answer(stream)
    const video = document.createElement('video')
    call.on('stream', userVideoStream => {
        addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream)
    })
  })  

  })

 socket.on('user-connected', (userId) => {
 //console.log("User Connected " + userId)
 connectToNewUser(userId, stream);
 })

 socket.on('user-disconnected', userId => {
 if (peers[userId]) peers[userId].close()
 })

  peer.on('open', id => {
  socket.emit('join-room', ROOM_ID, id);
 })




const connectToNewUser = (userId, stream) => {
const call = peer.call(userId, stream)
const video = document.createElement('video')
call.on('stream', userVideoStream => {
addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream)
})
call.on('close', () => {
  video.remove()
})

peers[userId] = call
}



  const addVideoStream = (video, stream) => {
video.srcObject = stream;
video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
    video.play();
})
videoGrid.append(video);
}


const muteUnmute = () => {
const enabled = myVideoStream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled;
if (enabled) {
  myVideoStream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled = false;
  setUnmuteButton();
  } else {
  setMuteButton();
  myVideoStream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled = true;
}
}

 const setMuteButton = () => {
const html = `
  <i class="fas fa-microphone"></i>
  <span>Mute</span>
`
  document.querySelector('.main__mute_button').innerHTML = html;
 }

 const setUnmuteButton = () => {
  const html = `
  <i class="unmute fas fa-microphone-slash"></i>
  <span>Unmute</span>
`
  document.querySelector('.main__mute_button').innerHTML = html;
}

  const playStop = () => {
  let enabled = myVideoStream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled;
  if (enabled) {
  myVideoStream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled = false;
  setPlayVideo()
  } else {
  setStopVideo()
  myVideoStream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled = true;
  }
 }

const setStopVideo = () => {
  const html = `
  <i class="fas fa-video"></i>
  <span>Stop Video</span>
`
document.querySelector('.main__video_button').innerHTML = html;
}

const setPlayVideo = () => {
const html = `
<i class="stop fas fa-video-slash"></i>
  <span>Play Video</span>
`
document.querySelector('.main__video_button').innerHTML = html;
 }
```

Face API code: 
Face API detects real-time facial expression from meeting room video for individual person and store data on database for specific user.

```
 const video = document.getElementById('video-play')

 Promise.all([
 faceapi.nets.tinyFaceDetector.loadFromUri('/models'),
  faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri('/models'),
  faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri('/models'),
  faceapi.nets.faceExpressionNet.loadFromUri('/models')
  ]).then(startVideo)

 function startVideo() {
 //   navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
  //     video: true
  // }).then(
 //   stream => (video.srcObject = stream),
 //   err => console.log(err)
// );

//const myVideo = document.createElement('video');
console.log(video);
video.muted = true;

let myVideoStream

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
video: true,
audio: true
}).then(stream => {
myVideoStream = stream;
addVideoStream(video, stream);
console.log("passed first stage");
})

const addVideoStream = (video1, stream) => {
video1.srcObject = stream;
video1.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
    video1.play();
})
 // video.append(video1);
console.log("passed second stage");
 }
 }

video.addEventListener('play', () => {
const canvas = faceapi.createCanvasFromMedia(video)
document.body.append(canvas)
const displaySize = { width: video.width, height: video.height }
faceapi.matchDimensions(canvas, displaySize)
setInterval(async () => {
const detections = await faceapi.detectAllFaces(video, new 
faceapi.TinyFaceDetectorOptions()).withFaceLandmarks().withFaceExpressions()
const resizedDetections = faceapi.resizeResults(detections, displaySize)
canvas.getContext('2d').clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
faceapi.draw.drawDetections(canvas, resizedDetections)
faceapi.draw.drawFaceLandmarks(canvas, resizedDetections)
faceapi.draw.drawFaceExpressions(canvas, resizedDetections)
 }, 100)
  })
```